# Multiple django model values depend on choice field value

Tags: python, django, django-models

My Django model has a `pricing_plan` choice field. There are 12 fields whose value depends on the `pricing_plan` value.

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    PRICING_CHOICES = (
        ('basic', 'Basic'),
        ('team', 'Team'),
        ('super', 'Super')
    )

    # some fields...

    pricing_plan = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='basic')
    max_host_accounts = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    max_admin_accounts = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    max_guests = models.IntegerField(default=10)

    # more fields whose value depends on pricing_plan value
```

For every different `pricing_plan` these fields get specific values. In code that could be described like:

```
if pricing_plan == 'basic':
    max_host_accounts = 1
    max_admin_accounts = 1
    max_guests = 10
    ...
elif pricing_plan == 'team':
    max_host_accounts = 10
    max_admin_accounts = 3
    max_guests = 25
    ...
```

However, there might be more pricing plans in the future and more options and I am afraid that an `if/elif/else` statement will be huge and not-easily readable.

What would be the best/idiomatic way to implement that in a Django model?

- Use more CHOICE tuples with constant values for every pricing plan?
- Use `Enum` classes with constant values for every pricing plan?
- Use Organisation as parent class and create subclasses 
  like:

.

```
class BasicOrganisation(Organisation):
    max_host_accounts = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    max_admin_accounts = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    max_guests = models.IntegerField(default=10)

class TeamOrganisation(Organisation):
    max_host_accounts = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    max_admin_accounts = models.IntegerField(default=3)
    max_guests = models.IntegerField(default=25)
```

- Anything else?

Comment: Only default values of the fields will be changing with every pricing plan?

Comment: check this django method https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Comment: @mkurnikov, actually yes. The fields will have fixed values (depending on the pricing plan). Even if we move to another plan, we can reset the values to the new default.

Comment: or check this to override save method http://fosshelp.blogspot.in/2010/12/django-override-save-method-two-ways.html

Comment: In nutshell get pricing_plan and save model and after that set default values for  other attributes

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that (I've used django-choices package for the pseudo-Enum emulation):

```
from django.db import models
from djchoices import ChoiceItem, DjangoChoices


def get_max_admin_accounts(pricing_plan):
    if pricing_plan == Organization.Pricing.BASIC:
        return 1
    # other code


class Organization(models.Model):
    class Pricing(DjangoChoices):
        BASIC = ChoiceItem('basic', 'Basic')
        TEAM = ChoiceItem('team', 'Team')
        SUPER = ChoiceItem('super', 'Super')

    pricing_plan = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=Pricing.BASIC)

    max_host_accounts = models.IntegerField()
    max_admin_accounts = models.IntegerField()
    max_guests = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.max_admin_accounts:
            self.max_admin_accounts = get_max_admin_accounts(self.pricing_plan)

        # other fields filled

        super().save(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    PRICING_CHOICES = {
        "basic": ("Basic", (1, 1, 10)),
        "team": ("Team", (10, 3, 25)),
    }

    # some fields...

    pricing_plan = models.CharField(choices=tuple([(i,j[0]) for i, j in PRICING_CHOICES.items()]), max_length=50, default='basic')
    #other fields

    def set_plan(self, max_host_accounts, max_admin_accounts, max_guests):
        self.max_host_accounts = max_host_accounts
        self.max_admin_accounts = max_admin_accounts
        self.max_guests = max_guests

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if getattr(self, "plan_changed", ""): #you need to set this attribute whenever updating a plan. like model_obj.plan_changed = True
            #otherwise you need to check db whether plan is changed or not.
            self.set_plan(*self.PRICING_CHOICES[self.pricing_plan][1])
        super(Organisation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```